# Удалил id модели Django, как вернуть?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Использую Django.

В models.py были такие модели:

```
class Stat(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    articul = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Я решил изменить структуру модели Product на

```
class Product(models.Model):
    articul = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

Теперь, при любом запросе к базе данных приходит ошибка

`operator does not exist: character varying = integer django`

База у меня очень большая, меня волнует два вопроса:

1. Это можно исправить не потеряв связи с таблицами?
2. Может можно вернуть старые id для таблицы? В этом случае могут слететь связи таблиц?

Заранее благодарен, проблема очень серьёзная, так как делал все на prod сервере

Comment: Тут речь не про удаление ID. Данные в таблицах остались абслютно теми же самыми, но резко поменялся способ, с которым Django ORM их интерпретирует. А физически в базе внешний ключ product как содержал id соответствующей базы, так и содержит как прежде. Просто сама библиотека теперь упорно пытается сравнить product (типа int - ссылающийся на id из таблицы product) и articul (типа varchar) вместо id.

Comment: Самый прямой путь, грубо говоря, нужно создать новый внешний ключ, заполнить его нужными данным, и удалить старый. А потом увязывать это с Django.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Такой способ рабочий, он очень долгий, так как у нас >50 млн записей
В итоге подняли бэкап

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, прежде чем применять изменения, затрагивающие базу данных и код проекта, убедитесь что не возникает ошибок)

По умолчанию поле ForeignKey ссылается на id-поле указанной модели. В вашем случае поле product ссылается на поле id в модели Product. Поле id создается по умолчанию и имеет аргумент primary_key=True. Все записи поле хранит в числах. Вы изменили первичный ключ модели и теперь Django не может использовать строку вместо числа.